# Writing and appending to a compound table in an HDF5 file in Julia

Tags: julia, hdf5

How can I write and append data to a compound table in an HDF5 with a column of variable length strings and other columns of various standard types (Int64, Float64, Bool)?

The basics are in Julia in some form or another. [HDF5.jl](https://github.com/JuliaIO/HDF5.jl) uses the HDF5 Group's C interface and [JLD2.jl](https://github.com/simonster/JLD2.jl) writes custom HDF5 files implemented entirely in Julia but I haven't found a way of creating, writing to, and appending to such a compound table yet.

My goal is to have a file which stores data from a number of instruments which is clearly annotated. As more data comes in it will periodically be appended to these HDF5 files. A binary file is needed to keep the files to a manageable size and a common standard is needed for portability amongst the programming languages used in our group. Databases aren't practical for our use case.

Comment: You're asking a complicated question. I know about one part, appending to HDF5Datasets, but I've never used compound types or variable length strings in HDF5. How far can you get with the docs? Can you make a compound data type with a variable length string? Do you know for sure that this is possible (eg can you do it in python)? I'm not sure extendible datasets in HDF5 work with variable length strings.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you will be able to do what you want to do, but I think that the best way forward for you is probably to read the HDF5 Users Guide to see how HDF5 works. The question posted here is so broad that it's akin to asking "How do I store data in a relational database?"

A few things to point you in the right direction, though:

- HDF5 is not a relational database and even though PyTables maps a tabular interface onto HDF5, it is semantically incorrect to refer to HDF5 tables and columns. Instead, there are HDF5 datasets which can store elements of a particular type. Those elements can be of compound type, which are roughly equivalent to C structs, and have 1 or more fields, which are also of particular types.
- If you want to store heterogeneous data, you are probably going to want multiple datasets. If you have multiple instruments, particularly if they have different data rates, I would probably store their data in different datasets. You could probably also use a giant dataset with a huge compound type that stores all your data for all your instruments but that would almost certainly be awkward, have worse performance, and not compress as well.
- I would avoid HDF5 variable-length types. They are awkward to use, the data can't be compressed, and performance is poor since they break locality (the dataset just stores a reference to a separate file location, where the real data are kept). Instead, think about flattening your data, either by concatenating the data and storing a separate dataset of indexes into the start/end points of the concat dataset, or by storing a fixed number of data points that is big enough to hold typical data. For example, if you need to store strings that are never going to be more than 100 characters long, just make an n x 100 dataset and compression will probably handle the extra nulls. Most people who think they need HDF5 variable-length types do not, in fact, need variable-length types. In fact, I would say that a majority of people who are new to HDF5 and inquire about vlen types actually just need extendable datasets.

The HDF5 User's Guide is located here:
https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/index.html

Comment: 1) It's quite clear HDF5 files are in no way databases. The term column however is quite descriptive and apt. Lacking a better alternative, they remain columns in anything I write.

2) Heterogeneous data isn't a problem for HDF5 files though I understand your point with variable length strings. Some of our data collection does on occasion require them so my question is referring to the worst case for our needs. It should go without saying that separate instruments and especially data streams with different measurement frequencies should be in separate datasets.

Comment: I am well aware of the HDF5 Group's documentation and have gone through it with my needs in mind. In addition I have dug through the HDF5.jl, JLD2.jl, and the HDF5 Group's C examples source code to find an answer. The answer may very well lie in any one of them but I have either missed it or misunderstood it.

This C example is basically what I'm looking to do but so far I haven't been able to replicate it in Julia, even using HDF5.jl's lower level functions. https://support.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/examples/misc-examples/sample-programs/compound.c

Comment: Appending data has been a point of confusion for me since the documentation seems to suggest that it's only possible by creating new tables or by using chunked datasets. I first did some tests in Labview and there it seemed like I could add as many rows as I felt like at a time. Using a named cluster even gave the columns useful names which makes looking at datasets in the field that much easier. It might just be that it chunk sizes of one row so it just seems like it supports appending data but I really don't know how developers of the Labview HDF5 package implemented it.

Comment: Yes, you can only extend chunked datasets. In the C API, you create the dataset using H5Dcreate and the dataspace you pass in needs to have its maximum size in the dimension you want to extend be set to H5S_UNLIMITED. You then call H5Dset_extent to change the size of the dataset. Be careful with your chunk size -- a very small chunk size will generate an enormous amount of file metadata and performance will plummet.

See here:

https://support.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/examples/introductory/C/h5_extend.c